# create post wordpress.com using rest api

Tags: php, rest, api, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress.com

I want to make php app to create post on wordpress.com using REST api.

I use this code:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init( 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'client_id' => 12345,
'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/wp/test.php',
'client_secret' => 'L8RvNFqyzvqh25P726jl0XxSLGBOlVWDaxxxxxcxxxxxxx',
'code' => $_GET['code'], // The code fromthe previous request
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$auth = curl_exec( $curl );
$secret = json_decode($auth);
$access_token = $secret->access_token;


$post = array(
'title'=>'Hello World',
'content'=>'Hello. I am a test post. I was created by
the API',
'date'=>date('YmdHis'),
'categories'=>'API','tags=tests'
);
$post = http_build_query($post);
$apicall = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/mysite.wordpress.com/posts/new";
$ch = curl_init($apicall);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array
('authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
charset=utf-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
$return = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($return);
exit;

?>
```

but I get this error:

> {"error":"unauthorized","message":"User cannot publish posts"}

Can help me?

Thanks

Comment: your `client_secret` definition is missing a `'`. And I hope this is not your real secret ...

Comment: i mistyped. i edited.. any idea for this error?

Answer (score 8):

Standard way to create posts is to use [cookies](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication) and nonce.

However I found a more easy way to do it.

1. Install [Basic-Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) plugin to your wordpress.
2. Create wordpress user with username `admin` and password `admin` (both credentials are **insecure**, used for demonstration purposes only)
3. Create post using code:

   ```
   $username = 'admin';
   $password = 'admin';
   $rest_api_url = "http://my-wordpress-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

   $data_string = json_encode([
       'title'    => 'My title',
       'content'  => 'My content',
       'status'   => 'publish',
   ]);

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rest_api_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
       'Content-Type: application/json',
       'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
       'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
   ]);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   if ($result) {
       // ...
   } else {
       // ...
   }
   ```

*Note that in example above version 2 of REST API is used.*

Comment: i dont think it can be done at wordpress.com.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right that we can use the "Basic-Auth" plugin to make a Rest API request.

But, @vallez want to create a post on wordpress.com website.

And wordpress.com provide the oAuth support for authentication.

---

Recently I have created a post which demostrate about using the oAuth to create a post on wordpress.com. You can read the article at [create the post on wordpress.com site using oAuth and Rest API](https://maheshwaghmare.com/create-the-post-on-wordpress-com-site-using-oauth-and-rest-api/)

Below are the steps to successfully create a post with oAuth on wordpress.com.

**Step 1:** Add authentication details to get auth key.

```php
$auth_args = array(
    'username'      => '',
    'password'      => '',
    'client_id'     => '',
    'client_secret' => '',
    'grant_type'    => 'password', // Keep this as it is.
);
$access_key = get_access_key( $auth_args );
```

Below is the function get_access_key() which return the access key.

**Step 2:** Get Access Key.

```php
/**
 * Get Access Key.
 * 
 * @param  array $args  Auth arguments.
 * @return mixed        Auth response.
 */
function get_access_key( $args ) {

    // Access Token.
    $curl = curl_init( 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $auth = curl_exec( $curl );
    $auth = json_decode($auth);

    // Access Key.
    return $auth->access_token;
}
```

**Step 3:** Set post arguments and pass it create the post.

```php
$post_args = array(
    'title'       => 'Test Post with oAuth',
    'content'     => 'Test post content goes here..',
    'tags'        => 'tests',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'categories'  => 'API',
);
```

**Step 4:** Create a post with the access key.

Now, We have access key and the create post arguments. So, Lets pass them to function create_post().

```php
create_post( $access_key, $post_args );
```

**Step 5:** Create a post with access key.

```php
/**
 * Create post with access key.
 * 
 * @param  string $access_key   Access key.
 * @param  array $post_args     Post arguments.
 * @return mixed                Post response.
 */
function create_post( $access_key, $post_args )
{
    $options  = array (
        'http' => array(
            'ignore_errors' => true,
            'method'        => 'POST',
            'header'        => array(
                0 => 'authorization: Bearer ' . $access_key,
                1 => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ),
            'content' => http_build_query( $post_args ),
        ),
    );
     
    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $response = file_get_contents(
        'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/YOURSITEID/posts/new/',
        false,
        $context
    );
    return json_decode( $response );
}
```

Comment: throwing error :{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): tags","data":{"status":400,"params":{"tags":"tags[0] is not of type integer."}}}