# How to use Wordpress Functions on an external PHP - On any wordpress site, not only mine

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on a PHP program that does some tasks and then generates a text, this text must be able to be published later in a Wordpress (.org).

The Wordpress sites where it will publish are not mine and are not on my server so include wp-load or similar will not to work, for this, I will have in my database the login information (URL of the site, user, password).

I need to know how to connect from PHP and create the session in Wordpress.
After that, I need to get the list of categories of the blog and then publish the generated text in one of them. Can it be done directly or do I need to make a plugin for this? I don't have experience making plugins and wordpress Rest API, so if there is a direct way it would be better.

Comment: wp-rest-api could be a good choice to use, so maybe consider to get knowledge. WP-session are created and managed internally by wp, you do not have control over them by outside. Can connect from outside only with rest-api or custom made wp-page which will handle a particular request.(same as rest by maybe better adjusted for something specific)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765474/create-post-wordpress-com-using-rest-api

Comment: thank you, this give me a good idea